# Inject EJB in ClientResponseFilter Jersey

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, ejb

I try to inject an EJB into a ClientResponseFilter using jersey. However, the EJB is always null. I read some resources online, but none of the solutions I found did work (also, I don't want to look after my bean by using InitialContext). Here is my filter

```
@Provider
public class MyResponseFilter implements ClientResponseFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyResponseFilter.class);

    @EJB
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        ...

       // using myBean always throws NullPointerException
       myBean.someMethod(); 
    } 

}
```

The code for MyBean:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class MyBean extends SomeAbstractClass {
...
}
```

I also tried adding the provider as a resource, with `resources.add(MyResponseFilter.class);`, but this also didn't work. Could someone please help me in solving this issue? I would like to use `MyBean` as it is, since it is used in a lot of other places and I am not sure I can catch all the side effects its change might have.

Thanks!